# Seperating the browser from the client

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, bridge, connection, client

I really like the simplicity and the interface of the tor browser's configuration and connection step. Maybe it is not as simple as the terminal but after trying to configure I had to admit defeat. I can't access tor without a bridge and I've come to learn that it is difficult for a beginner to configure files. Is there any way to use the client of the browser without letting the actual browser open up? Client should start and ask me to configure or connect and after it is done the browser shouldn't start is there a way to do that?

Comment: Which operating system?  Also, this always will require editing configuration files. There is no standalone GUI application, you will will need to learn how to use the CLI.

Comment: I am using linux mint latest at the moment. I understand that I need to edit the files. But I don't know the know-how of any of it though I am willing to learn. Can you give me a basic road map for the task if possible the rest is learning the commands and trying to edit it without breaking anything.